# How will Niantic determine the top 25% in #LuxAdventure quest to give The Lux Odyssey badge?

Tags: ingress

A new quest called [Lux Adventure](https://plus.google.com/+Ingress/posts/2ocJHk7LXBp) has been started on September 1st 2016 to get **Via Lux Adventurer Medal**. You should visit at least 300 unique portals to achieve it.

Also you can get a special medal called **The Lux Odyssey Medal** instead of Via Lux Adventurer Medal if you are in top 25% of those who exceed the 300 new unique portal visits.

The question is on how Niantic is going to sort the list?

Should I be in first 25% of all who hacked 300 unique portals or in 25% of all who get the most unique portal visit counts to get **The Lux Odyssey Medal**?

Comment: After reading the post, my understanding is the top 25% of people who visited the **most portals over 300**

Comment: Challenge accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically the 2 groups that you're describing should have the same set of elements (agents) in them and therefore be equal (unless you aren't defining **a group of users with only 300 new unique portal visits but not 301 and above**).

So in short if there are 1000 agents who have at least 300 new unique portal visits then all will get **The Lux Odyssey Medal**.

If say 600 of those 1000 agents have **more than 301 and above new unique portal visits** 150 agents (25%) in the top rank will get **The Lux Odyssey Medal**. (In this case I'm defining 1000-600=400 agents who have **exactly 300 new unique portal visits**).